# Alignment issues inside table

Tags: html, html-table

I have two divs which I put inside a table in order to get horizontally alignment.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
           data
         </div>
         <div>
            data
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Which looks like the following:

[image]

I now want to align these 2 in the centre, as opposed to the left.
I have tried `<td style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">`
but no joy.

Any idea?`

Comment: I'm not fully sure what "data" relates to, as there is no "data" within the image. However, why are you putting those dividers within your table cell in the first place? Why aren't you simply using `<td>data</td><td>data</td>`?

Comment: Could you add a little more code? Where are the elements in your image?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got it...should of been applying the style to the <table> and not the <td>'s

Answer (score 1):

Apply the `margins` to the `<table/>`:

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJBUe/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/GS6dD/2/)

use  align="center" for td  and for div use display: inline-block;

```
<table style="border: 1px solid green; width: 100%; ">
<tbody><tr>
  <td align="center">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;width: 30px;display: inline-block;">
       data
     </div>
     <div style="border: 1px solid red;width: 30px;display: inline-block;">
         data
     </div>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="containerdiv">
  <div id="coveringdiv">
    <div id="firstdiv">
      <div id="yourdata">
        Your Data Here
      </div>
      <div id="yourvalue">
        Value
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="seconddiv">
      <div id="yourdata">
        Your Data Second
      </div>
      <div id="yourvalue">
       values2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

> **and CSS:**

```
body
{
background-color: #123456;
}


#coveringdiv
{
border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#firstdiv
{
display: inline-block;
}

#yourdata
{
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 10px;
}

#yourvalue
{
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 24px;
}

#seconddiv
{
display: inline-block;
}
```